# Hibernate annotation configuration with Spring can't find domain object

Tags: hibernate, spring, orm, configuration, annotations

I am having a problem with Hibernate seeing my domain objects doing a purely annotation configuration for Hibernate.

I'm getting

`org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [from User u where u.userName=:userName]`

I thought all that had to be done was add the `packagesToScan` property for the sessionFactory and add `@Entity` to the domain object.  What else am I missing?

```
<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.trx.sample.domain" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="merge">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

-

```
package com.trx.sample.domain;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Column(name = "user_name")
  private String userName;
  private String password;
  private boolean enabled;
  private String roles;

  ...
}
```

-

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public boolean isNew() {
    return (this.id == null);
  }
}
```

-

```
[INFO] building session factory
[DEBUG] Session factory constructed with filter configurations : {}
[DEBUG] instantiating session factory with properties: {...}
[DEBUG] initializing class SessionFactoryObjectFactory
[DEBUG] registered: 402881e52a6b3159012a6b3163e40000 (unnamed)
[INFO] Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
[DEBUG] instantiated session factory
[DEBUG] Checking 0 named HQL queries
[DEBUG] Checking 0 named SQL queries
```

Edit:

Don't know if it makes a difference or not but I'm running it through eclipse on a tomcat instance.

Comment: Hibernate is pretty verbose when it starts up, and it should mention each class as it gets mapped. What does it say?

Comment: It doesn't indicate it's mapping anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hanging my head in shame as I answer this.  The @Entity import was incorrect.

This particular domain object used

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
```

when it should have been using

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

gah!

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: `USER` is a [reserved keyword](http://www.petefreitag.com/tools/sql_reserved_words_checker/?word=user) with some databases, maybe this is preventing Hibernate from being properly initialized. I suggest escaping it:

```
package com.trx.sample.domain;

@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`")
public class User extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Column(name = "user_name")
  private String userName;
  private String password;
  private boolean enabled;
  private String roles;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  Didn't seem to fix it though.  I just know this is some stupid little thing I've overlooked and am going to feel like a moron once I find it.

Comment: @Josh Then it's something else :) Sorry for stating the obvious but don't you get any particular message at `SessionFactory` creation time? Is `User` the only entity that failed to be recognized? Do you have other entities from the same package that are properly recognized?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set annotatedClass or packagesToScan properties in your SessionFactoryBean. see [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html)

Comment: I am doing that.  See the post.

Comment: I am sorry, i didn't see it. We are using annotatedClass in our application and it is functional. I tried looking for reason why packageToScan didn't found classes, but without success. Try to set debug level for logging in Hibernate or debug Springs AnnotationSessionFactoryBean. It is possible, that Hibernate uses other classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Could yo be missing this?

`<property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"/>`